# Searching in Dired for content in files while filtering files

Tags: dired, search, find-dired, find

From Dired, I'd like to be able to search for content pretty much like I do on my MAC Finder, while showing the files that match the criteria/regular expression (and no other files). I don't want the matching files to be marked, but rather filtered from the rest of the files in the folder. Is there a good online source where to find possibilities? I want something simple (if it's done inside the Dired menu, even better, rather than relying on other packages).

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Have you tried `find`? Have you tried `find-dired`? Have you tried omitting files that match or don't match a regexp from those shown in the listing? It's not clear just what you've tried (and why that doesn't satisfy you) or what you're trying to do exactly. Dired offers many possibilities, but to answer your question we need to know just what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the built in `find-grep-dired`. From the documentation:

> Find files in DIR that contain matches for REGEXP and start Dired on
> output.

Try <kbd>C-h f find-grep-dired RET</kbd> to know more.